# Extracting only certain indexes

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following array and I just want to get the index 7 and 8 from every element. Is there a Linq way to do this without creating a class ?

[image]

When I do this `split.Select(d => d.ElementAt(7)).ToList()`
I create new array with element 7 but I also need the element 8 here.

I tried `split.Select(a => new { a[7], a[8] }).ToList()` but I get a message that says

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: it would make your post a lot better if you first attempted something whether it works or not and then ask your question based on that.

Comment: Right, something like split.Select(d => d[7]).ToList(); gets me the index 7 but I need the index 7 and 8.

Comment: So, what is the result which you expect? Is it a list of array with 2 items each? Or a list of tuples? Or a list of custom class? How you want these two strings to be represented?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create reduced array with two selected indexes.

Comment: @nPcomp update your post with any code or extra information instead of doing so in the comments section. Also, if you include the expected result it would make life easier for everyone.

Comment: `split.Select(a => new []{ a[7], a[8] }).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will yield a `List<string[]>`

```
split.Select(a => new[] { a[7], a[8] } ).ToList();
```

and the following `List<List<string>>`

```
split.Select(a => new List<string> { a[7], a[8] } ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I need.